# How can I get data from memory mapped file?

Tags: visual-c++, memory-mapped-files, file-read

I have text file with the name By_a_waterfal.txt and the following content:

```
By a waterfal I'm calling you.
We can share it all beneath a ceiling of blue.
We'll spend a heavenly day
Here where the whispering waters play.
```

I create memory mapping of this file by calls of function:

```
HANDLE hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(handleOfFile, NULL, PAGE_READ, 0, 0, NULL);
```

Where handleOfFile is the handle of By_a_waterfal.txt file.
Then I do the following call:

```
LPVOID lpFileMap = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
```

How can I get access to content of the memory mapped By_a_waterfal.txt file via the view created with MapViewOfFile call?

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to use memory mapping instead if std::ifstream, then:

1) Check lpFileMap for NULL.

2) Get size of view as GetFileSize(handleOfFile) or VirtualQuery(lpFileMap).

3) If file has ANSI encoding (not Unicode) cast lpFileMap to char* and proceed (do not forget that there is no 0-terminator)

```
auto data = static_cast<const char*>(lpFileMap);
std::string strData(data, size);
std::cout << stdData;
```

Answer (score 0):

`lpFileMap` is a pointer to the content.  If you want the content as a `const char*` for instance, just cast it:

```
const char* content = static_cast<const char*>(lpFileMap);
```

Comment: So, I can iterate through the content as through the string variable? But if mapped file has a large size, for example 20GB. And in this case what is the best way to have access to data in view of memory mapped file?

Comment: Yes, you can iterate through the contents as if it were a string I suppose, depends on what your data is.  If the mapped file can't be allocated in one piece of memory, then `lpFileMap` will be null.  In which case the best way is to map a smaller chunk each time.  See `dwNumberOfBytesToMap` in the [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation